# VARCHAR(MAX) not accomodating full string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, varcharmax

I have a `varchar(max)` defined but it is truncating the string.

I have searched for the solution and found that all the new values assigned or appended to the string should be cast to `varchar(max)` but it still didn't help.

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @tr VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT
    @tr = CAST(CAST(@tr AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + 
               CAST(ISNULL(CONCAT
                (
                    '<tr>',
                    '<td class="dataline">',t.ComponentEquipmentNumber,'</td>',
                    '<td class="dataline">',t.ComponentDescription,'</td>',
                    '<td class="dataline">',t.ReceiverCustodian,'</td>',
                    '<td class="dataline">',t.[Location],'</td>',
                    '<td class="dataline">',t.ParentSystemNumber,'</td>',
                    '<td class="dataline">',t.ParentSystemLocation,'</td>',
                    '<td class="dataline">',t.RootSystemNumber,'</td>',
                    '<td class="dataline">',t.RootSystemLocation,'</td>',
                    '<tr/>'
                ),'') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
FROM 
    #TempFinal t 
ORDER BY 
    EquipmentId
```

You can see I have put cast to `VARCHAR(MAX)` on all levels just to make it works, but it still didn't work.

And when I try to print the length of the string `print len(@tr)`, it returns this strange number `76788` which is not even equal to `8000` characters of `VARCHAR(MAX)`, not getting the logic of this number.

Please help!

Comment: That strange number is the length of the final string, and if it's greater than 8000 that means the `VARCHAR(MAX)` is doing its job (the maximum length of that is 2^32 - 1 characters, not 8000). How are you establishing that the string is truncated? Specfically printing it or displaying it in SSMS may truncate it there while the actual value is correct.

Comment: probably is only truncating in the results window

Comment: `PRINT` will only print up to 4,000 characters and the maximum characters in a single "cell" in the grid view is 65535 characters. If you need more than that, you need to export the data another way.

Comment: why you are saving such big data in single `varchar` variable in `sql`. It is not gonig to be saved anywhere, so what is the use of this expression in sql?

Comment: My *guess* is that the OP is going to pass the value to `sp_send_dbmail`, considering they are creating table HTML, @DarkRob .

Comment: @pawan: can you post further code where do you want to use this, there might be some other way so that you don't need to create this string.